# Best programming language for beginner

Tags: stack, overflow

I've just got into coding. Wanted to know which would be the best and the easiest programming language to learn.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please take the [tour] and read about [ask] good questions. Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: And why not continue with the one you're currently learning? As a beginner, it will take time to learn all the intricacies and be ready to learn another language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't know anything about coding I would say go for python. It's simple and easy to understand.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please take the [tour] and read about [ask] good questions, and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly read about [how to write good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).